# In nodejs why export a function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm seeing this kind of module export in some nodejs code

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    doSomething: function doSomething() {
      console.log('doing something');
    }
  };
};
```

so this is exporting a function that returns an object, that itself has a function `doSomething` on it. What's the point of this technique? why not just export the object (rather than a function that returns the object)?

```
module.exports = {
  doSomething: function doSomething() {
    console.log('doing something');
  }
};
```

why not just export the `doSomething` function?

```
module.exports = function doSomething() {
  console.log('doing something');
};
```

Comment: You can export everything what you want, object, function or a variable.

Comment: "What's the point of this technique?" Nothing. The code as it is, is pointless.

Comment: With such a minimal example, it does indeed seem pointless. But if either the exported function or `doSomething` have arguments or open resources like files or communication channels then it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the use case. Both approaches are correct. One of the use cases for the first is the ability to define private methods without exposing them. This common pattern is used for creating APIs.

```
module.exports = () => {

  // private method
  privateMethod () {
    // This method is private to this module

  }
  return {
    doSomething: function doSomething() {
     // use privateMethod() here
     console.log('doing something');
   }
};
```

**Update:**

However, this approach returns a function that can be invoked later. Because this is a function it can receive parameters at the site of call.

```
module.exports = (args1, args2) => {
  return {
    doSomething: function doSomething() {

     console.log(`This is argument ${args1} and argument ${args2}`);
    }
  }
};
```

// Then, at the site of call, we can have

```
const module = require('<path to file>')('Rowland', 'Ekemezie');
module.doSomething() // -> This is argument Rowland and argument Ekemezie
```

Comment: why the downvotes? is this wrong? makes sense to me. so it's basically acting to define a class with an empty constructor. is this not correct?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mentrie/Document-Management-System/blob/master/server/api/routes/role.route.js) is one instance where I used it. Instead of instanting the express router for each routes file, I have it passed down from the index file.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is **caching**.

According to [Node js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and
>   call that function.

Code example that gets executed on each `require`:

```
function HelloWorld() {
  this.greeting = "Hello, World";
  return this;
}
module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

Code example that gets cached and executes only on the first `require`:

```
var HelloWorld = (function () {
  this.greeting = "Hello, World";
  return this;
})();
module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

Comment: But this is not what the op's example is doing.

Comment: @James How is it different? OP is asking what's the difference between exporting an object or a function(that returns an object, although it does not matter), hence the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the following code to directly export a function.

//In controller

```
exports.functionName=(async (req,res))=>{
return res.send(req.body)
}
```

//To import in another file

```
const {functionName}=require('./controller')
```